# ComboBox don't see initialize in dropdown

Tags: excel, vba, combobox

i want to insert some values into the ComboBox. But i cannot choose "Initialize" from the dropdown.. can someone help me?
Picture for intelligibility

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you got to do it there :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

//your code here

End Sub
```

Comment: What did it return, Can you edit your issue and add what you tried pls ?

Comment: ah sorry it was my fault.. i did the initialize directly into the field and not the UserForm.. thanks for help its solved

Comment: i want but stack overflow say i have to wait 1 minute

Comment: @Mike Glad I could help you !